# Change text to BOLD in WTP(Windows Troubleshooting Pack) - Troubleshooting Manifest

Tags: xml, windows, winapi, desktop-application, diagnostics

I am trying to create a Windows troubleshooting package and want to display certain text, in the Troubleshooting wizard, in **BOLD**.

A short snippet of my Troubleshooting Manifest (XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<dcmPS:DiagnosticPackage SchemaVersion="1.0" Localized="false" 
 xmlns:dcmPS="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/dcm/package/2007" 
  xmlns:dcmRS="http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/dcm/resource/2007">

    <DiagnosticIdentification>
        <ID>TESTID1</ID>
        <Version>1.0</Version>
    </DiagnosticIdentification>

    <DisplayInformation>
        <Parameters />
        <Name>
            <dcmRS:LocalizeResourceElement comment="Comment" 
            index="100">Test HelpWizard to fixconflicts</dcmRS:LocalizeResourceElement>
        </Name>

        <Description>
            <dcmRS:LocalizeResourceElement comment="This is a comment" index="0">
This wizard will help configure your computer so that you have the necessary tools to start your work.    
     </dcmRS:LocalizeResourceElement>
        </Description>
    </DisplayInformation>
</dcmPS:DiagnosticPackage>
```

---

Output:

[image: This]

---

Is there a way to highlight the text, "Test Help-Wizard to fix conflicts", within the `<name>` in bold ?

I have tried wrapping the text using

- `<b>`Test Help-Wizard to fix conflicts`</b>`

But XML does not validate and throws an Error 
**"The Element 'http://www.microsoft.com/schemas/dcm/resource/2007:LocalizeResourceElement' cannot contain child element b because parents elements content model is text only**

- `<![CDATA[<b>Test Help-Wizard to fix conflicts</b>]]>`
  XML Validation completes but the Output on Wizard shows the `<b>` `</b>` tags literally

I have also read the official documentation on creating troubleshooting packs, writing manifests, resource schema, but couldn't find a solution

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323761(v=vs.85).aspx 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323708(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that this is even possible? Regarding `<b>`, notice that the above XML application has nothing to do with HTML.

Comment: I'm hoping it is possible, It's got something to do with the schema's defined 
and `<b>` is also used in XML https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_syntax.asp

Comment: No. XML is a meta-language used to create specific languages, called "XML applications". XML therefore has no elements at all! But for each XML application, there is a set of possible elements. XHTML includes `b`, a book cataloguing format might include `isbn`, a graph format might include `node`, a film database might contain `director` etc. The W3Schools page you refer to simply uses non-specified example applications to describe the characteristics of the XML meta language. Really, the Microsoft Troubleshooting Manifest  XML application has nothing to do with XHTML.

Comment: The text in question already is set apart from the remainder of the message, purely by the dialog's layout. Why do you believe, that you need to provide extra strong highlighting on text, that already is visually emphasized?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand, right, does that mean that this is not possible ?

Comment: @IInspectable yes, on the homepage it is distinct by the layout, however in the subsequent user interaction screen's I would like to be able to emphasize some text in BOLD and maybe also add some picture of my choice to the wizard to guide the end-user effectively !!!!

Comment: @Clint: It is probably not possible using HTML markup, at least. Also, I suspect there is no reasonable easy way at all to do this. (But nothing is impossible: after all, you could create your own EXE in plain C++ that looks just like such a wizard.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I figured that it is possible to change the Font properties by using `<RTFDescription>` tag within `<ExtensionPoint>` `</ExtensionPoint>`

To begin with, `<ExtensionPoint>` will allow you to customize your user Interface even further.

**What is `<RTFDescription>`** ?

> Allows you to add Rich text format to your Interactions. The
>   RTFDescription element can contain an RTF string or a localized
>   resource string (for example, "@diag.dll,-123" or
>   "@diag.dll,RESOURCE.RTF")

A snippet of my code to modify the font

```
<ExtensionPoint>                       
 <RTFDescription>
     <dcmRS:LocalizeResourceElement comment="This is a comment" index="10">

# Text in RTF Syntax
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fswiss\fprq2\fcharset0 Calibri;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}}
{\colortbl ;\red112\green48\blue160;}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa160\sl252\slmult1\cf1\f0\fs24 Step 1: Enter Profile name\par
Step 2: Enter Email address\par
\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\cf0\lang9\f1\fs22\par
}

     </dcmRS:LocalizeResourceElement>
 </RTFDescription>
</ExtensionPoint>
```

**Output** :

[image]

---

Official Documentation is provided here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776530.aspx